# SDL - BlitSurface copies whole source surface onto the whole destination surface even though I specify a destination rectangle

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to understand why SDL_BlitSurface copies the whole source surface onto the destination surface even though I have a destination rectangle smaller than screen width and height.

The problem is here:

```
SDL_Rect rect;
rect.x = 0;                             
rect.y = 0;
rect.w = SCREEN_WIDTH-200;
rect.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT-200;
SDL_BlitSurface(optimizedSurface, NULL, screenSurface, &rect);
//Update the surface
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
```

This is what appears
[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Here is my reproducible code.

```
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <bits/atomic_base.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* window = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

//The surface of the loaded media
SDL_Surface* optimizedSurface = NULL;

bool loadMedia() {
    bool success = true;

    char path[] = "/home/gras/CLionProjects/SDLBonanza/resources/cock.bmp";


    SDL_Surface* loadSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path);

    if(loadSurface == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to load image: %s with error msg: %s", path, SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    //optimize image on load to remove conversion when blitting
    optimizedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(loadSurface, screenSurface->format, NULL);

    if(optimizedSurface == NULL) {
        printf("The optimised image could not be computed with error: %s", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadSurface);

    return success;
}

bool init() {
    bool success = true;

    //initialize sdl
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize with error code: %s", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

        if(window == NULL) {
            printf("The window could not be created with error: %s", SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
        else {
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            if(screenSurface == NULL) {
                printf("The screen surface could not be created with error: %s", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}

void close() {
    //dealocate surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(screenSurface);
    screenSurface = NULL;

    //dealocate window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;

    //quit sdl subsystem
    SDL_Quit();
}

void negative() {
    for(int i=0; i<optimizedSurface->h; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<optimizedSurface->w; j++) {
            Uint8* pixel = ((Uint8*)optimizedSurface->pixels + i * optimizedSurface->pitch + j * optimizedSurface->format->BytesPerPixel);
            for(int k=0; k< optimizedSurface->format->BytesPerPixel; k++) {
                *(pixel+k) = 0xFF - *(pixel+k);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    if(!init()) {
        printf("The initialization failed!");
    }
    else
        if(!loadMedia()) {
            printf("The media could not be loaded!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Hack to get window to stay up
            SDL_Event e;
            bool quit = false;
            while( quit == false ) {
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) ) {
                    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                        quit = true;
                    if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                        switch(e.key.keysym.sym) {
                            case(SDLK_UP):
                                negative();

                                SDL_Rect rect;
                                rect.x = 0;
                                rect.y = 0;
                                rect.w = SCREEN_WIDTH-200;
                                rect.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT-200;
                                SDL_BlitSurface(optimizedSurface, NULL, screenSurface, &rect);

                                //Update the surface
                                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    //free and destroy window
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the original image:

[image]

Comment: From the "Remarks" section of the documentation: "Only the position is used in the dstrect (the width and height are ignored)."

Comment: @Botje well thank you, I don't know how I missed that. Thank you very much!